# Customize MobileNet model architecture with Tensorflow Object Detection API

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network, object-detection

Tensorflow object detection API provides a number of pretrained object detection models to choose from. However, I would like to introduce modifications to the architecture of those models.

Particularly, I would like to make Faster RCNN into a more shallow network and use it to train my model. I want to gain in performance despite loss in accuracy. MobileNet is too inaccurate for my application.

Is it possible to achieve this without having to implement everything from scratch ?

Thank you.

Comment: did you manage to accomplish this? if so can you please post your code? thanks.